# How to organize a complexe git repo?

Tags: git, version-control

Here is the problem: at work we have some old and crappy SVN repos. Most of them come from even older CVS repos. No way to know which branch is the last, no commit in the trunk for years (literally), some libraries are duplicated on several repos... the whole thing is a giant mess.

I convinced the guy supposed to be the tech lead to switch to a clean git solution.
Of course, I'm the one designated for this.
We'll keep the old SVN somewhere just in case we need to search for an old commit, so no need to convert the repo and keep SVN history into git.
The idea is really to make something clean and handy.

The projet is pretty big, about 2.5M lines.
It mainly consists of:

- ~25 linux exe
- 3-4 big Windows exe
- ~15 libraries, shared by most of the previous exe

I read a few things about branching strategies, submodules and stuff, but when it comes to apply theory to a big real things, that's not easy to handle...
The branching strategy would be [something like this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

I thought about two solutions:
 - One repo for windows exe, one for linux exe, and a third for the libraries. This last repo would be referenced as a submodules by the other two.
 - One repo for each and lib. Looks a bit overkill to me, and I guess it requires a lot of scripting to be comfortable. On the other hand, it makes it  lot easier to have a distinct version number for each binary.

What would be the best strategy to map my projects to git repos?
How can I mix the branching strategy with submodubles?

A few hints:

- It would be really nice to be able to identify the version number of each exe/lib.
- Most of the time, changes are spread among a bunch of exe and libs.
- My coworkers are not used to git and I'd like to keep it simple. So I want to avoid overcomplicated solutions that would require lots of commands to achieve simple and common tasks.
- The libraries are static for the moment, but will probably switch to dynamic in a few month, so It would be nice to be sure that all linux exe use the same version of each lib.

**edit**

Basically, all executables depend on several libraries.
Currently, executables are released by OS. For example if a feature is added in a linux exe, a few libs and the exe will be modified, and all linux exe will be released and delivered to the client. In that way, all the executables will contain the same version number, corresponding to the linux part, which is based on an SVN tag. If there is no modification on the Windows part of the projet, it won't be released.

The build system is basic: the linux part has a makefile at the root of the repo, and then each exe/lib has it own subdirectory with its own makefile. Everything is builded for a release.
On the Windows side, we have a Visual solution with all the needed libs and the executable as projects, so everything is build as well (but the version number is set manually).

QA is only a dream here.
Each released is (quickly) tested by the developper, then by the client before it goes to production (sometimes, client tests are skipped!).

Comment: What do you mean by `OS exe`? Do you literally store executables in your version control?

Comment: No, only source code.

Comment: There really is no silver bullet and the correct answer depends on the answers to other questions such as "How do you manage releases of libraries and executables?", "Which projects depend on each other?", "How do you do QA and integration testing?", "How does your build system work?".